# How to schedule python job to run every hour accurately with the schedule package

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule

I am using the schedule python package and would like to run a job every hour at the :00 mark.

Is this possible?

This is the code I have right now:

```
def schedule_jobs(self, loop):
    logging.info('Starting scheduler...')

    schedule.every(1).hours.do(self._pldown_runner.run_pldown_job, loop)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

The problem with this is that it runs the job every hour starting from the minute it was actually executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the schedule api supports it:

```
schedule.every().hour.at(":00").do(my_job)
```

Comment: So, if for example I wanted to execute every 2 hours at :00, I do something like:

schedule.every(2).hours.at(":00").do(my_job) ?

Comment: exactly. As you wrote, you should indeed change 'hour' to 'hours'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!